# pdf reader online files

Tags: xcode, pdf

I use a PDF reader called vfr to read local pdf files. I also tried to read online pdf files but it didn't work.

This the code:

```
- (IBAction)didClickOpenPDF {

    NSString *pdfURL = @"www.ciep.fr/tcf/document/manuel_candidat.PDF";
    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:pdfURL password:nil];

    if (document != nil)
    {
        ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
        readerViewController.delegate = self;

        readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

[Link to ZIP file.](http://cl.ly/2V0q3O2T230B)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What are you trying to do? What is it that doesn't work? Do you get error messages? What have you tried? Please answer these questions so we can help you get answers. Thank you.

Comment: thank you no errors messages i had i would like to know if there is solution to read pdf online with this code i tried but it was difficult for me. i hope that you help me

Comment: no question in the body... and this is too localized IMO -- what is ReaderDocument?

Comment: this a link for to the project http://cl.ly/2m1h3H163l3b

Comment: i would like to read from online pdf file not local

Comment: You can also make a webview with the pdf file in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the following senario...

```
  1 - Save the file to the local storage

  2 - read the full path/local url of the downloaded file

  3 - invoke didClickOpenPDF with the path/local url of the PDF
```

i hade the save issues and i solved it using this senario